# Partial Text Replace with Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Trying to replace Your Price with Discount price on this [page](http://bit.ly/unxGy0), what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready ( 
    function() { 
        $("td:contains('Your Price:')").text("Discount Price:"); 
    } 
);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your HTML - or preferably, a demo?

Comment: @AlexPeattie Code is listed in the link attached to page.

Comment: That text is not inside a table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pricetag = $('.yourprice').html().replace('Your','Discount');
$('.yourprice').html(pricetag);
```

this should work for that website, just include that inside the document ready

http://jsfiddle.net/uTJbu/

or

```
$('.yourprice').html(($('.yourprice').html().replace('Your','Discount')));
```

Comment: $('.yourprice').html(($('.yourprice').html().replace('Your','Discount'))); that is even shorter 1 line.

Comment: Thanks Owen, short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you look it up with contains when you have a class on it already?

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_YourPriceDiv" class="yourprice">
    Your Price: <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_YourPriceLabel">$959.20</span>
    <span class="thcustom"><br />Free Shipping</span>
</div>
```

The selector should just be that class name.

```
var elem = jQuery(".yourprice");
elem.html( elem.html().replace("Your Price:","Discount Price:") );
```

Comment: Thank you @epascarello, your answer helped me figure out another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the "Your Price:" in a:

`<span id="lblPrice"> then $("#lblPrice").text("Discount Price:")`